# noSelectionOption Attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF and I came across the `noSelectionOption` attribute in JSF 2.0.

I don't understand the purpose of this attribute. As per the description, it's used when the selection is required and the user selects `noSelectionOption` causing a validation error.

So, if `noSelectionOption = true` then the user can select `noSelectionOption` and bypass that list or menu?

Or, if `noSelectionOption = true` then the user has to select one of the items, and, if he chooses `noSelectionOption` then the validation error occurs?

Can the user see `noSelectionOption` as one of the items under the List or menu if it's true?

Please help me to understand the logic behind this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `f:selectItem` that has `noSelectOption` set to true represents a "no selection" option, something like this:

```
-- Select a Colour -- < noSelectOption was intended for this case
Red
Green
Blue
Tomato
```

This item is rendered in the menu, unless `hideNoSelectionOption` is set to true in your menu component. In that case, the option is selected when the user interacts with the menu.

Just bear in mind that if an entry is required and this "no selection" option is the one selected, there will be a validation error.

An alternative that requires a little more of coding is to use a `f:selectItem` with `value="#{null}"`, to represent the case in which an user did not select a value. If you have a converter you'll have to check for this `null` case and, if you feel like it, introduce some custom validators.

Comment: How to change the error message for the validation error? requiredMessage or validatorMessage doesn't change it.

Comment: @user1643352 Depends on which kind of validation you're triggering. If it's just a `required="true"` validation, you can check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/) out but be warned, it will change the message for all of the `required` validations. You can, on the other hand, register a custom validator and assign your own messages. Depends on the kind of validation you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I have not understood why `value="#{null}"` is more complicated. Just set `required="true"`. I continue to not understand the purpose of `noSelectionOption`