# Provide a wildcard f:selectItem value in p:selectOneMenu with dynamic data and Converter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<p:selectOneMenu>` component, that is fed with an Array of instances of some Class (say ClassABC). In the top of the selectItems list, I want to provide a `<f:selectItem>` that will serve as a Wildcard/Any option, and it's value should be a null object.

I managed to make this work as

```
<p:selectOneMenu  
        value="#{someBean.selectedInstance}"
        converter="classABCDConverter" >
    <!--  Wildcard Value -->
    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" * Any * " itemValue="" />

    <!-- Dynamic Data with Real Instances -->
    <f:selectItems 
        var="result"
        value="#{someBean.arrayOfInstancesOfClassABCD}"
        ....
         />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So far this seems to work, as selecting the -any- select item, gives a null Object to `someBean.selectedInstance`. I guess that `itemValue=""` makes the Converter return a null object,   so it probably looks legit.

But I'm  just curious if this is the safest and most efficient way to go.

EDIT: Alternatively I could use `noSelectionOption="true"`
so, for example, which would be better from the 2 bellow :

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel=" * Any * " itemValue="" />
```

or

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel=" * Any * " noSelectionOption="true" />
```

Comment: At least this one works for hundreds of selectOneMenus for me, so I do hope that this is a safe way to go :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf)

Comment: you also have a `noSelectionOption="true"` in `<f:selectItem>`

Comment: thanx for the tip on noSelectionOption. I was pretty much searching for something like that. But is this declaration safer than 'itemValue=""'

Comment: @Xtreme Biker : right, I missed that question, although I gave some time searching before posting my question

Comment: The only difference I think is that `noSelectionOption` doesn't call the converter while `itemvalue=""` does. In summary, `noSelectionOption` is the way to go, the JSF standard one.

Comment: If you use a `required="true"` in the `<p:selectOneMenu>`, it is safer to go with `noSelectionOption` since it will fail validation and show a "required" message (if you use it). Like @XtremeBiker said, it will not invoke the converter and avoid returning an empty string or something like that...