# includeViewParams=true converts null model value to empty string in query string

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, viewparams

Given a `<p:selectOneMenu>` as follows.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{testManagedBean.id}" converter="javax.faces.Long"/>
</f:metadata>

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{localeBean.language}" onchange="changeLanguage();">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="hi" itemLabel="Hindi" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:remoteCommand action="#{testManagedBean.submitAction}"
                 name="changeLanguage"
                 process="@this"
                 update="@none"/>
```

The corresponding managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class TestManagedBean {

    private Long id; //Getter and setter.

    public TestManagedBean() {}

    public String submitAction() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
    }
}
```

The parameter as indicated by `<f:viewParam>` is optional. A page, for example is accessed using a URL as follows.

`https://localhost:8181/Project-war/private_resources/Test.jsf`

Since `id` is an optional parameter, an empty parameter is attached to the URL (when a language is changed from `<p:selectOneMenu>`), in case it is not supplied as follows.

`https://localhost:8181/Project-war/private_resources/Test.jsf?id=`

This should not happen. An empty parameter should not be appended, if it is not supplied and the URL should look like the first one.

Is there a way to prevent an empty parameter from being appended to the URL, when it is not passed?

---

**This is only associated with the converter as specified with `<f:viewParam>` - `javax.faces.Long`.**

If this converter is removed then, parameters are not appended to the URL, in case no parameters are supplied.

Although specifying a converter as demonstrated here is completely unnecessary, I have converters as shown below to convert an `id` passed though the URL as a query-string parameter to a JPA entity.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class ZoneConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private final SharableBeanLocal sharableService = null;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        try {
            long parsedValue = Long.parseLong(value);

            if (parsedValue <= 0) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Message Summary", "Message"));
            }

            ZoneTable entity = sharableService.findZoneById(parsedValue);
            if (entity == null) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Message Summary", "Message"));
            }

            return entity;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Message Summary", "Message"), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return value instanceof ZoneTable ? ((ZoneTable) value).getZoneId().toString() : "";
    }
}
```

This converter is now required to be specified explicitly with `<f:viewParam>` as follows.

```
<f:viewParam name="id" 
             value="#{testManagedBean.id}"
             converter="#{zoneConverter}"
             rendered="#{not empty param.id}"/>
```

And the associated managed bean needs to be changed as follows.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class TestManagedBean {

    private ZoneTable id;  //Getter and setter.

    public TestManagedBean() {}

    public String submitAction() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `required="false"` for your `<f:viewParam>`?

Comment: Tried setting `required` of `<f:viewParam>` to `false` but that didn't make a different either.

Comment: Some mistakes/not best practices you've got in your post: **1.** `*.xhtml` is used as mapping pattern in order than `*.jsf` starting from JSF 2.x. **2.** You forgot to tell about `#{bean}`'s implementation. **3.** You wrap a lot of irrelevant code for your question: the managed properties are not related with your case, neither the `p:remoteCommand`. Remove them and minimize your test case till you can reproduce the issue with the minimal code. If you keep having it, post it as it is. See [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) question formatting.PD:I made a test case about your issue with no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely an oversight in [Mojarra's default implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.5/javax/faces/component/UIViewParameter.java#UIViewParameter.getStringValueFromModel%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) of [`UIViewParameter#getStringValueFromModel()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/component/UIViewParameter.java#UIViewParameter.getStringValueFromModel%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) whose source is for reference copypasted below:

```
384    public String getStringValueFromModel(FacesContext context)
385        throws ConverterException {
386        ValueExpression ve = getValueExpression("value");
387        if (ve == null) {
388            return null;
389        }
390
391        Object currentValue = ve.getValue(context.getELContext());
392
393        // If there is a converter attribute, use it to to ask application
394        // instance for a converter with this identifer.
395        Converter c = getConverter();
396
397        if (c == null) {
398            // if value is null and no converter attribute is specified, then
399            // return null (null has meaning for a view parameters; it means remove it).
400            if (currentValue == null) {
401                return null;
402            }
403            // Do not look for "by-type" converters for Strings
404            if (currentValue instanceof String) {
405                return (String) currentValue;
406            }
407
408            // if converter attribute set, try to acquire a converter
409            // using its class type.
410
411            Class converterType = currentValue.getClass();
412            c = context.getApplication().createConverter(converterType);
413
414            // if there is no default converter available for this identifier,
415            // assume the model type to be String.
416            if (c == null) {
417                return currentValue.toString();
418            }
419        }
420
421        return c.getAsString(context, this, currentValue);
422    }
```

This method is called for every `UIViewParameter` (the UI component behind `<f:viewParam>`) during building the query string for `includeViewParams=true`. We see in the source that it calls the converter regardless of whether `currentValue` is `null` or not. In other words, even if the model value is `null`, it still calls the converter with it.

As per the [javadoc of `Converter#getAsString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html#getAsString%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.Object%29) converters are by specification required to return a zero-length String if value is `null`:

> ### getAsString
>
> ...
>
> **Returns**: a zero-length String if value is `null`, otherwise the result of the conversion

So, converters are actually supposed to never return `null` on `getAsString()`. They return an empty string then. In case of view parameters in query string, this is highly undesirable. The difference between an empty string value and a complete absence in query string is really significant.

I've reported it to Mojarra guys as [issue 3288](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3288). They should then fix this problem as follows:

```
391        Object currentValue = ve.getValue(context.getELContext());
392
393        if (currentValue == null) {
394            return null;
395        }
```

In the meanwhile, I've [committed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/760d3b6a963f5383f83f82a756afe82112e2586e) a solution to OmniFaces. The [`<o:viewParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam) has been extended with this fix. It's available as per today's [1.8 snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.8-SNAPSHOT/).

```
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="id" value="#{testManagedBean.id}" converter="javax.faces.Long"/>
</f:metadata>
```

---

**Update**: they decided to not fix it. In any case, there's OmniFaces.

Comment: Looks like maybe now they are reconsidering at the spec level: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1180