# p:inputText and p:selectOneMenu strange interaction on IE 10

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am using PF4.

Here's the strange situation I am facing.

Everything goes well on FF.

On IE 10 (compatibility mode or not) I have a page with a p:wizard

On wizard step 1, user fills a p:editor

On wizard step 2, user clicks on a row from a `p:treeTable`. When this happens, an ajax event is triggered to enable / disable / show / hide several input elements, like this

```
<p:ajax event="select"
        listener="#{jobEngine2MB.onNodeSelect}"
        update=":form:input"/>
```

The fields are rendered correctly (3 `p:inputText` and 1 `p:selectManyMenu`) but sometimes, only the last `p:inputText` is enabled.

And consistently, all `p:inputText` are enabled if I select any value for the single `p:selectManyMenu`. (no JavaScript event is showed in IE developer tools console tab related to that). This `p:selectManyMenu` has no ajax event attached (not explicitly I guess).

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="userCategory"
                 value="#{jobEngine2MB.userCategory}"
                 rendered="#{jobEngine2MB.showUserCategory}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select User Category"
                  itemValue="#{null}" />

    <f:selectItems value="#{jobEngine2MB.userCategoryList}"
                   var="ds"
                   itemLabel="#{ds}"
                   itemValue="#{ds}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Upgrading to PF5+ is not an option because there are a lot of pagination code for data tables I'd have to rewrite since the API has changed from one version to another.

Any idea or workaround?

ps. the only suspicious thing I have here

```
SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
editor.js.xhtml, line 9 character 8782
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'select' of undefined or null reference 
editor.js.xhtml, line 9 character 11507
```

Comment: with respect to the following question and answer, the problematic part is probably setting f:selectItem value to #{null}. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052503/using-a-please-select-fselectitem-with-null-empty-value-inside-a-pselectonem

Comment: actually, it started working when I've replaced p:editor with p:inputTextarea

Comment: one more thing to keep in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working when I've replaced p:editor with p:inputTextarea

Seems to be related to the javascript errors mentioned in the end of the post.

Also happens with PF 5.1