# Issue when a selctItem with null value is select in selectOneMenu Primefaces component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The env: 
Mojarra 2.2.12
Primefaces 5.3
Glassfish 4.1.1

JSF page

```
........
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="system" value="#{permissionController.permission.system}"
                                     converter="entityConverter"
                                     >
                        <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{permissionController.buildObjectTypeList}"
                                update="permission_details_panel" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['please.select']}" itemValue="#{null}" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{permissionController.systems}" var="_system" itemValue="#{_system}"
                                       itemLabel="#{_system.name}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
..........
                </h:panelGroup>
```

Converver class

```
@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter extends SelectItemsConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Object o = super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
        if (null == o) {
            return null;
        }
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (null == value || !(value instanceof IEntity)) {
            return null;
        }
        IEntity entity = (IEntity) value;
        if (null == entity.getId()) {
            return null;
        }
        return  entity.getId().toString();
    }
}
```

**Scenario**

1. Select a system in the selectOneMenu component with id="system"- a buildObjectTypeList method is called on the backing bean
2. Select a default "Select One..." item which has null as a value on the same component - the buildObjectTypeList method is **NOT** called on the backing bean

That happens because when an item with null value is selected, the value from itemLabel comes to the converter's `getAsString` instead of the null. So when it happens the 'value' parameter in the `public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)` will have "Select One..." as a value and later based on this value a current item will be select on the JSF page. Obviously there no such item, because the item's value is `null`

This issue was already raised not even once, but was never addressed. Below are the links. I used a workaround, but it is heavy and looks too synthetic for this issue. It would be nice if the the actual value from `f:selectItem` was passed to the coverter instead of a value from itemLabel attribute, but I have no idea how I can make it to work this way.

Does it look like a Primefaces framework problem?

[primefaces selectonemenu change event not working for null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279696/primefaces-selectonemenu-change-event-not-working-for-null-value)

[<p:ajax> not firing when choosing null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766054/pajax-not-firing-when-choosing-null-value)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24321980/1391249

Comment: @Tiny you are right. Thank you. Just have not found the correct one

Comment: That may happen quite often :)